# Get users's FID, Name and Email after login with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get the user's FID, Email and Name after login with Javascript so I make an Ajax call and save them to the database.

This is currently the code to login users:

```
    if (response.status === 'connected') { // the user is logged in and connected to your application
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        // Alert with fid, email and name
        } else { //the user isn't logged in to Facebook or isn't connected to the application
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                // Alert with fid, email and name
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }
```

How can  I do it?

Comment: where are you exactly stuck ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid,name,email FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

You'll need the

```
email
```

permission